# Application behaves weirdly when made to run on device

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

I have created an application that has a lot of pages and the user navigates from one to another according to his needs. The application runs smooth when I'm running it from the PC, but as soon as I put the .apk file in the device and make it run independently it behaves erratically.

It opens random pages on Button Click which are supposed to appear after a few frames. My best guess is that incorrect intent passing etc is causing this and that's why I'm tagging this question with Intents.

Can this be happening because I am not firing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP while I'm moving from activity A ->B but only when the user presses the back button B -> A.

Any help here is appreciated !!

PS: Though I don't see the need for any code, please comment in case someone needs to see it.

Comment: Sounds more like code algorithm issue.. you might be interested to check onNewIntent(). Better if you post your code snippet..

Comment: What code do you want to see? The simple passing intents and on back press passing an intent to the home screen along with clearing the stack with the **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** command.

Comment: Are you passing any parameter to activity B which is used to show "pages" in your activity B? Activity B should be finished once you are using the CLEAR_TOP intent flag. How are you firing the intent flag if you are not starting activity A from B and using onBackPress?